# Best software for Android Device On Ubuntu?

Tags: updates, sync, htc

I have HTC Android Device and I am Using Ubuntu 13.10, I need a No the Best But If it's Best That OK A software For Sync and Update Device. Urgent Suggest Need here>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can be use gMTP.

More info on Ubuntu Apps:
https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/saucy/gmtp/

*Note that you have to turn on the option to use **mtp** transfer on you android confi storage section.